# Creating CFDictionaryRef with CFDictionaryCreate and special characters

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, special-characters

We need to do somthing with a user generated password.
We have case where the password contains a `ä`, but when we create a `CFDictionaryRef` from it the framework changes the character to `\U00e4`.

```
const void *keys[] =   { somObj};
const void *values[] = { (CFStringRef)[passwords objectAtIndex:i] };

CFDictionaryRef optionsDictionary = CFDictionaryCreate(NULL, keys, values, 1, NULL, NULL);
```

Is there a way to have the `\U00e4` replaced by `ä` in the directory?

Comment: `\U00e4` is the unicode representation of ä. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: @AnthonyLawrence when i further use the dictionary, i need to decypher a cert, and i know the phassphrase has the ä character. But when i use the decypher method it fails, letting me know it is not the correct passphrase

Comment: @Frederiek: Perhaps you can add some code how the dictionary is further used and where you get the unwanted output. Note that NSLogging a dictionary uses `\Unnnn` escape sequences for all non-ASCII characters, but that should not matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More likely than not, your string encoding is not being preserved.   As Anthony said, `\U00e4` **is** `ä`.   That is UTF-16.  In UTF-8, it'd be `0xC3 0xA4`.   UTF-32?  `0x000000E4`.

You need to treat the password like a buffer of raw data.   Upon entry -- making sure that the entry itself is in the right encoding -- stick it in an NSData and leave it there.

Comment: yep you are right, after checking deeper into the code, we see that the problem isn't located there. thanks for the help anyway